# Add Calendar Web Part w/SharePoint 2010 and Summary View

Tags: calendar

I am trying to add a calendar web part to the default.aspx page within a feature. The calendar gets placed on the form but I would like the default view to be the summary view. I have read that if you set the ViewGuid to string.Empty it will set the view to the summary view but this is not working.

Ideas?

```
// Calendar 
ListViewWebPart calendarWP = new ListViewWebPart(); 
SPList calendarList = site.Lists["Calendar"]; 
calendarWP.ListName = calendarList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(); 
calendarWP.ViewGuid = string.Empty; 
oWPManager.AddWebPart(calendarWP, "Left", 3);
```

Comment: I am trying to set to 'All Events' without success as well..help?

Answer (score 2):

Try the approach using feature XML [described by Yaroslav Pentsarskyy](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/09/09/programmatically-provisioning-sharepoint-2010-calendar-view-on-pages/).

```
<View List="Lists/Calendar"
BaseViewID="2"
Type="CALENDAR"
Scope="Recursive"
RecurrenceRowset="TRUE"
WebPartZoneID="BottomLeft"
WebPartOrder="0" />
```